# How to reuse variable - Error: Pattern appears on the right-hand side of rule

Tags: warning-messages, variable-definitions

I do not know enough about *Mathematica* to understand why the following statement won't save the variable for me for later use:

```
x_fake = Table[i, {i, 1, 100}]
```

It generates a list of fake x values from 1 to 100 with increments of 1. I want to use this list later to plot:

```
ListPlot[x_fake]
```

But it doesn't work and throws the errors

> "Rule: Pattern x_fake appears on the right-hand side of rule..." and "ListPlot: x_fake is not a list of numbers or pairs of numbers"

Although the reason must be very simple, I can't seem to find a straightforward answer. The [Wolfram docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions.html) indicate that in Mathematica there is a difference between immediate and delayed execution, so I tried the delayed execution syntax

```
x_fake := Table[i, {i, 1, 100}]
```

But it throws the same errors.

How can I save `x_fake` and reuse it like I can with R or any other normal programming language?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The underscore is a reserved character. Effectively, you are writing

```
Pattern[x, Blank[fake]]
```

you can see this by looking at `FullForm[x_fake]`. You then get the message whenever you try to use it because `x_fake`, a `Pattern`, appears on the right hand side of a rule, like `Set` or `SetDelayed`. Variable names must start with a character, but otherwise can contain a mix of characters and numbers. Note, this includes the full character table, such as `\[Alpha]`.

As an example found in [ref/ImplicitRegion](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion.html), this uses `\[ScriptCapitalR]`

[image]

Comment: Ha. Simple. Thank you.

Comment: This should probably be in the [pitfalls](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/121) post since some form of it has come up fairly often.  Would you consider writing that?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard it already [is](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/52), although it likely could be improved.